# Refrence error in gatsbyjs createPage object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blogs, gatsby

I keep getting this error when I try to create a blog page using the [`createPage`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) code from the Gatsby node API documentation.

Here is my code:

```
module.exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
const {createPages} = actions
const blogTemplates = path.resolve('./src/templates/blogTemplates.js')
const res = await graphql (`
    query{
        allMarkdownRemark{
            edges{
                node{
                    fields{
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`,

res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach((edge) => {

    createPage ({
        component: blogTemplates,
        path: `/blog/${edge.node.fields.slug}`,
        context: { 
        slug: edge.node.fields.slug
        }
    })
})
)}
```

This is the error message I got:

ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

allMarkdownRemark is not defined

ReferenceError: allMarkdownRemark is not defined

- gatsby-node.js:35 Object.module.exports.createPages
  C:/Users/Mr Prewsh/Desktop/gatsby-bootcamp/gatsby-node.js:35:5
- api-runner-node.js:235 runAPI
  [gatsby-bootcamp]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:235:41
- api-runner-node.js:375 Promise.catch.pluginName
  [gatsby-bootcamp]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:375:13
- new Promise
- api-runner-node.js:374 runPlugin
  [gatsby-bootcamp]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:374:10
- api-runner-node.js:328 module.exports
  [gatsby-bootcamp]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:328:24
- index.js:437 module.exports
  [gatsby-bootcamp]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:437:9
- develop.js:420 async module.exports
  [gatsby-bootcamp]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/develop.js:420:7

failed createPages - 0.506s

**Below is my gatsby-config file**

```
require("dotenv").config({

  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,

  }),


module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  // plugins: [
  //       'gatsby-plugin-sass'
  // ]

  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'My Gatsbysite',
    author: 'Mr Prewsh'
},

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          camelCase: false,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: what does your gatsby-config.js file look like? Check this https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/

Comment: i just edited the question, its added

Comment: A guess: if your markdown files are not in `src`, try adding a new instance of `gatsby-source-filesystem` with the md folder as its path

Comment: I think the error is because you are adding `query` to your GraphQL query.
I would just do: 

`allMarkdownRemark{
            edges{
                node{
                    fields{
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: After I removed the query in my graphql, I started getting a type error that says ``cannot read property node of undefined``.